# Object of type CharField is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django by trying to build what comes to the mind. Now I'm trying to build Django rest API
that returns item or all items from a postgres data table.

models.py

```
class AdModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    web = models.CharField(max_length=50),

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mock_location_data'
```

serializers.py

```
class AdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = AdModel
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'web']
```

views.py

```
class AdAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = AdModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AdSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

On GET request I'm getting Internal server error 500 with "Object of type CharField is not JSON serializable"

in views.py if replace fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'web'] with

```
fields = '__all__'
```

I'm getting all the id fields

```
[  {    "id": 1  },  {    "id": 2  },  {    "id": 3  },.....]
```

but no other data

I'm using Django 3.1.5 and DRF 3.12.2

Comment: There's a few things going on here but the thing that stands out is that you have commas at the end of your model's fields, this turns them into tuples and thus not valid model fields

Comment: My god, how could I not see this. Am i doing anything wrong except this rookie mistake ?

Comment: The only obvious thing is: don't define an `id` field, let Django automatically create one for you and the one you have in your model is not even being initialised/called so I don't really know how it's working

Answer (score 2):

You missed a pair of parentheses in your AdModel class's id field and also don't need "," after each field:

```
class AdModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    web = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```